# How to use custom names for django core migration tables?

Tags: django, django-migrations

The Django core migrations create the following tables

```
    auth_group
    auth_group_permissions
    auth_permission
    auth_user
    auth_user_groups
    auth_user_permissions
    django_admin_log
    django_content_type
    django_migrations
    django_session
```

But I would like to add `acps` before each of the table names like the following.

```
    acps_auth_group
    acps_auth_group_permissions
    acps_auth_permission
    acps_auth_user
    acps_auth_user_groups
    acps_auth_user_permissions
    acps_admin_log
    acps_content_type
    acps_migrations
    acps_session
```

That is because I would like to run multiple instances of Django in the same database.

I am using `SQL Server` and `Django 2.1.8`

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in core Django, however, there is a package available to prefix all tables across the project:

https://github.com/fingul/django-db-prefix

Good luck!